# Mix of constant and "dynamic" option values

Tags: c++

I have a value that can take one of the following semantic values (they don't make sense out of context but the exact context isn't important):

- By Request Only
- On Event Only
- Automatic With Interval *N* (where *N* is an integer from 1 to 200)

Internally all of these are represented by a single integer:

- By Request Only = 0
- On Event Only = 252
- Automatic With Interval *N* = *N* (where *N* is from 1 to 200)

I want to represent this value with a type named `MessageType`, and I want to pass this value to a function `setMessageType()`, with both as members of a class:

```
class Example {
public:
   // <= definition of MessageType would be here. 
   ...
   void setMessageType (int id, MessageType type);
};
```

I want this type to meet the following requirements:

- Usage of it is clear (e.g. constants named `ByRequestOnly` and `OnEventOnly`).
- Usage of "automatic with interval" is clear *and* enforces that *N* is in the appropriate range *at runtime*, (e.g. `Automatic(50)`).
- It is critical that a developer using this type cannot inadvertently pass an unintended value (weird casts aside); that is, I want the same level of compile time semantics that an `enum` provides, with the exception of runtime validation of the "automatic" value range.
- The "automatic with interval" value should be conveniently constructable given an `int`.

In other words, I'd like to be able to write code that looks something like this:

```
Example example;
example.setMessageType(0, Example::ByRequestOnly);
example.setMessageType(0, Example::OnEventOnly);
example.setMessageType(0, Example::Automatic(1));
example.setMessageType(0, Example::Automatic(200));
int n = ...; // from 1 to 200
example.setMessageType(0, Example::Automatic(n));
example.setMessageType(0, Example::Automatic(500)); // <= throws exception
```

And in `setMessageType()` I'll need to convert the value to its internal representation:

```
void Example::setMessageType (int id, MessageType type) {
    int internal = type.internalValue(); // e.g. 252 for OnEventOnly
    ...
}
```

I am having a really hard time defining a type that meets all of the above requirements. One possibility is to just use an integer type equal to the internal representation:

```
class Example {
public:
    typedef int MessageType;
    static const int ByRequestOnly = 0;
    static const int OnEventOnly = 252;
    // use integer value 1-200 for interval
};
```

Problem: Any `int` can be used with no semantics. No validation of automatic interval setting done.

I also tried using a `struct` with a mix of constant values and static functions:

```
class Example {
public: 

    struct MessageType {
        friend class Example;
    private:
        explicit MessageType (int iv) : internalValue_(iv) { }
        int internalValue_;
    };

    static const MessageType ByRequestOnly = MessageType(0);

    static const MessageType OnEventOnly = MessageType(252);

    static MessageType Automatic (int interval) {
        if (interval >= 1 && interval <= 200)
            return MessageType(interval);
        else
            throw runtime_error("Invalid automatic interval.");
    }

};
```

Problem: This does not compile, as constructors cannot be used in constant expressions.

Another thing I could do is use a huge enum:

```
class Example {
public:
    enum MessageType {
        ByRequestOnly = 0,
        OnEventOnly = 252, 
        Automatic_1 = 1,
        Automatic_2 = 2,
        Automatic_3 = 3,
        ...,
        Automatic_200 = 200
    };
};
```

But this is extremely cumbersome, both to implement, and especially to convert an `int` to one of these values for "automatic" (runtime checking of automatic value would be done in the implementation of conversion from an int to the enum).

How can I do this? How can I define some type that gives me similar compile-time behavior to an `enum` but also allows for a "dynamic" range of certain values with runtime checks for those cases?

Comment: I had trouble thinking of a title. If anybody can think of a better title, please feel free to edit. Sorry if it is vague.

Comment: You have to use templates and template specialization to meet the requirement: 'It is critical that a developer using this type cannot inadvertently pass an unintended value (weird casts aside); that is, I want the same level of compile time semantics that an enum provides.'. Anything else, including your struct, can't verify Automatic's range until runtime.

Comment: @adpalumbo I actually meant for the range to be verified at runtime, editing post to clarify.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `Example` class would compile if you put the initialization of the static constants in a source file, not in the header.

```
class Example {
public: 

    struct MessageType {
        friend class Example;
    private:
        explicit MessageType (int iv) : internalValue_(iv) { }
        int internalValue_;
    };

    static const MessageType ByRequestOnly;

    static const MessageType OnEventOnly;

    static MessageType Automatic (int interval) {
        if (interval >= 1 && interval <= 200)
            return MessageType(interval);
        else
            throw runtime_error("Invalid automatic interval.");
    }

};
```

Elsewhere in a cpp file

```
const Example::MessageType Example::ByRequestOnly = Example::MessageType(0);
const Example::MessageType Example::OnEventOnly = Example::MessageType(252);
```

Comment: This is perfect! I must have been staring at this too long, I didn't think to move them to a source file. I am going to leave this question open for a bit longer to see what others have to say but right now it looks like I'm going to implement it this way. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

My immediate thought is to not make your constants of type `Example`.  You might even make them different types.

```
struct Example {
    static const RequestType {} ByRequestOnly;
    static const EventType {} OnEventOnly; 
    struct Automatic {
        explicit Automatic(int v) 
            :value(v)
        {
            if(value<1 || value>200)
                throw std::runtime_error("Invalid automatic interval.");
        }
    private: 
        friend Example;            
        int value;
    };

    void setMessageType (int id, RequestType type) {internal = 0;}
    void setMessageType (int id, EventType type) {internal = 252;}
    void setMessageType (int id, Automatic type) {internal = type.value;}

private:
    int internal;
};
```

Comment: This seems like a good idea; then internally I could just have a private `setMessageType (int id, int internalValue)` with the actual implementation, and these just call that.